# Veryfing double value in MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core

I am currently working on app to see my crypto trades. One of my properties TradeCryptoAmtBought is of type double.

```
public double TradeCryptoAmtBought { get; set; }
```

In my view where I'm logging in my new trade I have to fill in this amount. For example buying 0.002 Litecoin. When passing this value I always get this error

```
The value '0.002' is not valid for TradeCryptoAmtBought.
```

Razor markup:

```
    <div class="form-group">
        <label asp-for="TradeCryptoAmtBought" class="control-label"></label>
        <input asp-for="TradeCryptoAmtBought" class="form-control" />
        <span asp-validation-for="TradeCryptoAmtBought" class="text-danger"></span>
    </div>
```

Anyone can help on this issue? I tried lot of DisplayFormats,

```
[DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{#.##}")]
```

but I always end upo with the same error

Comment: you should be using `decimal` for currencies

Comment: had the same issue so I tried double instead

Comment: Do you have any special culture (localization) used?

Comment: You can try to use [RegularExpression](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.componentmodel.dataannotations.regularexpressionattribute?view=net-5.0).

Answer (score 0):

try changing the dataformat string to something like:

```
{0:0.####}
```

for extra info about formats visit the link below:

[https://www.csharp-examples.net/string-format-double/#:~:text=For%20two%20decimal%20places%20use,the%20number%20will%20be%20rounded.&text=Next%20example%20formats%20double%20to%20string%20with%20floating%20number%20of%20decimal%20places](https://www.csharp-examples.net/string-format-double/#:%7E:text=For%20two%20decimal%20places%20use,the%20number%20will%20be%20rounded.&text=Next%20example%20formats%20double%20to%20string%20with%20floating%20number%20of%20decimal%20places).

Answer (score 0):

As you are using this field for currency values it is better to use the decimal datatype. Also to apply formatting on editors you need to set the ApplyFormatInEditMode to true. Try editing your data annotation to this:

```
// Display currency data field in the format $1,345.50.
// Also, apply format in edit mode.
[DisplayFormat(ApplyFormatInEditMode=true, DataFormatString = "{0:C}")]
```

For more examples: [DisplayFormatAttribute Class](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.componentmodel.dataannotations.displayformatattribute?view=net-5.0#examples)